# Web based chat that has group chat features?

Tags: webapp-rec, chat

I currently use IMO.im, which is great except they don't offer group chat... I'm looking for something similiar but with that feature.

Required:

- Group chat (like a desktop app)
- Web based (no desktop apps!)
- Support gTalk/Aim/Msn/Skype

Nice to have:

- Chrome plugin
- "off the record" type feature

Edit: Sorry I should have mentioned that I'm absolutely fed up with Gmails built in chat - if I receive one more "Soandso hasn't received your message" notification, I might jump off a cliff. (The worst part is that we tested it in office, and sometimes people DO get the messages, and it still shows the error). Also I need MSN/Skype.

The group chat doesn't have to work accross protocols. Just needs to support group chat for the individual protocols. (In other words I don't need to invite Skype contacts to a Google Talk group chat).

Answer (score 3):

[Meebo](http://meebo.com) supports all of your required protocols expect [Skype](http://skype.com).

It has good support for group chat, I use it as my primary IM client and I'm very satisfied. There is no Chrome extension available as far as I know, but with the new 'instalable webapp' feature of chrome, I have it permanently open in one of those smaller tabs. Perfect!

I haven't been able to find an "off the record" feature, although i'm not quite sure what you mean by that...

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I didn't remember this one, tried it a long time ago. Vote up. Thanks.

Comment: Does Meebo allow *video* chat?

Comment: Yes, it does. When I'm in a chat with someone, a "video chat" is shown in that box. I never tried it though...

From http://www.meebo.com/meebo/ : "Just click any of the shiny icons in your Meebo Messenger IM window to launch applications like games, video chat, and file transfer."

Comment: This is no longer an option, [Meebo got acquired by Google and shutdown](https://www.meebo.com/support/article/175/).

Answer (score 2):

Gmail's inbuilt chat. Now has Group Chat too.

Comment: See edits to question - also - needs to support more protocols. VD.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that whilst there are other on-line chat solutions most of them require you to use [IM Group](http://imgroups.net/) for setting up group support across gTalk/MSN/Yahoo! (no Aim/Skype).

Alternatives for on-line instant messengers can generally be be found via [this Google Search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=site%3aim+online+instant+messenger&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) even Trillian (popular some years back) has a [web version](http://www.trillian.im/).

Comment: Don't need to support multiple protocol group chat. See edits.

Comment: Webuzz.im requires that you download something.

Comment: My bad - replace webuzz.im with http://www.iloveim.com/ - there are just sooo many to choose from (look at http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=site:im+online+instant+messenger&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=).

Answer (score 1):

Try [imo.im](http://imo.im/). It has group chat, is web-based and supports common chat services like GTalk, AIM, MSN and even Skype. It also has a [Chrome notifier app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jefcommcgcjfonaaclmhmkefbngjdnlk).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- http://koolim.com
- http://imo.im
- http://anologue.com

If you care about security try Bonchat:
http://bonchat.org/

No accounts, just a link and a password to decrypt the chat client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Banckle Group Chat http://banckle.com/products/group-chat/default.html is a secure web-based online chat solution for all types of businesses. It is fully customizable and users can set up password protected public or private chat rooms. They can easily share images, files and videos while they chat or collaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Tlk2me](http://www.tlk2me.com) which is a simple, easy to use, group chat application. It lets you quickly create new chat rooms and invite your friends along. No ads, no account creation, no non-sense, it’s all free.

> "Tlk2me is simple real-time chat designed for groups. You can invite your friends, clients, or colleague to chat, collaborate, and make decisions…"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the HTML5 chat widget called [RumbleTalk](http://www.rumbletalk.com).

> RumbleTalk is a chat service that enables websites owners to add a chat to their online experience.
>   With RumbleTalk you have the flexibility to create a unique chat designed for a website or a blog.